# Combine Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a couple of javascripts that slow my website performance down a lot.
The list is :

```
                    http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/jquery.min.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/main.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/skel-viewport.min.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/skel.min.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/util.js
     http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/js/overzicht.js
```

I tried to "copy" the contents of some of the scripts into one of the existing. But...no succes. As I need to call these scripts from somewhere. How do I identify a .js  script nested in another .js file ? I someone can help me with an example of combining two .js files,  I will puzzle te rest myself. 
Thanks.

Comment: Combining/minifying those scripts is most likely not the source of the speed issue on the site - it's more likely to be the code you are executing using them. Also note that the first library should really be included *after* jQuery as it relies on it. You should also *never* put spaces in your folder names on a web server.

Comment: Profile your web page in order to know which scripts take too long to load.

Comment: Thanks for your swift responses.  I will get rid of the space also thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by profiling the webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed up your website you can try the following:

- Use CDN version for common libraries like jquery in this way you get performance 
  availability/security out of the box for free.
- Concatenate and minify your application JS. This allow to minimaize the number of network requests (concatenation) and the amount of code code send down to the browser (minification). There are several task utility project to accomplish both tasks automatically (and more) and they can be included in your work flow with little effor, example gulp or grunt.
- Use Google Page Speed or similar to analyse your site, example: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ 
  these tools usually provides further hints on how to optimize your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can `speedup` your script files by `minifying` JavaScript codes.

Here is some online JavaScript minifier links -

- https://javascript-minifier.com/
- https://jscompress.com/
- http://www.minifier.org/

> Also you can use `CDN` script for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different approach for this. Loading the files asynchronously. setting the async attribute to the script tag will make the file to load asynchronously. This helped me in different situations to improve my performance.

Example: `<script src="http://loketgevondenvoorwerpen.nl/New%20Design/assets/js/jquery.min.js" async></script>`

You can check the difference in performance (with async and without async) in the browser dev tools.